# How to implemente squircle formula in Matlab?

Tags: geometry, circles, matlab

So I am trying to plot a Squircle in Matlab. I would like to use the formula below

$$\left|\frac{x - a}{r_a}\right|^p + \left|\frac{y - b}{r_b}\right|^p = 1$$

I am not sure how to deal with the absolute value and to solve it for y?

ps. Yes I saw [this post](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/498108-how-do-i-draw-a-squircle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MATLAB in my pc but I think the following will work:

```
a=1; b=3; c= 5; d= 2; p=2;
syms f(x,y)
f(x,y) = (abs(x-a)/c)^p +(abs(y-b)/d)^p - 1;
fimplicit(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have a picture of a [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) or "squircle", there are plenty of online graphers like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) that can do it for you. Desmos even lets you put sliders in to control the length, width, and "squircularity" (i.e. the power $p$). See pic:

[image]

*Note: I'm using $h, k, a, b$ here instead of the OP's notation because those are the variables typically used in writing an ellipse: $$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1,$$ where $(h, k)$ is the center, $a$ is the semi-horizontal diameter, $b$ is the semi-vertical diameter.*

In terms of graphing as a function, you will need 2 functions, one for the top half and one for the bottom half:

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{x - h}{a} \right|^p &+ \left| \frac{y - k}{b} \right|^p = 1 \\
\left| \frac{y - k}{b} \right|^p &= 1 - \left| \frac{x - h}{a} \right|^p \\
\frac{y - k}{b} & = \pm \sqrt[p]{1 - \left| \frac{x - h}{a} \right|^p} \\
y &= k \pm b\sqrt[p]{1 - \left| \frac{x - h}{a} \right|^p} \\
\end{align*}

So the top half equation is $$y = k + b\sqrt[p]{1 - \left| \frac{x - h}{a} \right|^p}$$ and the bottom half equation is $$y = k - b\sqrt[p]{1 - \left| \frac{x - h}{a} \right|^p}.$$

You could also use a fractional exponent $1/p$ instead of the $\sqrt[p]{}$ to write these equations.